# Support for table/grid widget in final-cut?

Tags: c++, tui, finalcut-tui

**The question is about TUI C++ library https://github.com/gansm/finalcut.**

- What is the best way to show a key:value pair in a widget? I use for the moment FLabel objects for that (with different colors for the key and the value). But let me continue...
- How to show a list of key:value pairs?
- And pushing it even further, how do I show a table? Any plans to support it in the future?

I use final cut version 0.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

The Final Cut has no widget which is able to handle key-value stores. It would be really interesting to have a widget that shows standard container elements directly without having to insert the items separately. But you can fill a FListBox widget with values from an associative container.

```
using namespace finalcut;

FListBox*  list = new FListBox (this);
list->setGeometry(FPoint(1, 1), FSize(7, 7));

std::map<char,int> ascii;
std::map<char,int>::iterator iter, begin, end;

ascii['@'] = 0x40;
ascii['A'] = 0x41;
ascii['B'] = 0x42;
ascii['C'] = 0x43;
begin = ascii.begin();
end = ascii.end();

for (iter = begin; iter != end; ++iter )
  list->insert (iter->second);

// Jump in the list to item ascii['B']
int n = int(std::distance(begin, ascii.find('B') ));
list->setCurrentItem(n+1);

// Stupid indirect access: value that is mapped to key 'C'.
n = int(std::distance(begin, ascii.find('C') ));
FListBoxItem item = list->getItem(n+1);
FMessageBox::info (this, "Value[C]", item.getText());
```

In the future, a widget named FListView is also planned. Here it will be possible to have more than one column.  This should allow you a tabular representation of your data.

Or you clone the current git repository and use the brand-new FScrollView widget. Here you can place several FLabel widgets on a scrollable viewport. (Beware: FScrollView is still under development)

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of the final cut git repository, the FListBox widget is able to import data from an STL Container. You can import data directly on inserting or later on the first access via "lazy conversion". All you need's a little helper function.

**Direct import**

```
#include <final/final.h>

using namespace finalcut;

static FString* temp_str = 0;

// Direct import helper functions
FString& IntToString (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter)
{
  return temp_str->setNumber(*iter);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FApplication app(argc, argv);

  FDialog dialog ("List example", &app);
  dialog.setGeometry (FPoint(30, 2), FSize(22, 22));

  FListBox list (&dialog);
  list.setText ("Direct import");
  list.setGeometry (FPoint(1, 1), FSize(20, 19));

  int n = 0;
  temp_str = new FString;
  std::vector<int> v(100,0);
  std::vector<int>::iterator iter = v.begin();

  while ( iter != v.end() )
  {
    n++;
    *iter = n;
    ++iter;
  }

  list.insert (v.begin(), v.end(), IntToString);
  delete temp_str;

  app.setMainWidget(&dialog);
  dialog.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

**Import via lazy conversion**

```
#include <final/final.h>

using namespace finalcut;

// Lazy conversion helper functions
void IntToString (FListBoxItem& item, FDataAccess* container, int index)
{
  auto& vec = flistboxhelper::getContainer<std::vector<int>>(container);
  int n = vec[index];
  item.setText ("      " + FString().setNumber(n));
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FApplication app(argc, argv);

  FDialog dialog ("List example", &app);
  dialog.setGeometry (FPoint(30, 2), FSize(22, 22));

  FListBox list (&dialog);
  list.setText ("Lazy conversion");
  list.setGeometry (FPoint(1, 1), FSize(20, 19));

  int n = 0;
  std::vector<int> v(100, 0);
  std::vector<int>::iterator iter = v.begin();

  while ( iter != v.end() )
  {
    *iter = n;
    (n%2 != 0) ? n++ : n+=3;
    ++iter;
  }

  list.insert (v, IntToString);

  app.setMainWidget(&dialog);
  dialog.show();
  int ret = app.exec();
  return ret;
}
```

*Last modified: Code changes for the upcoming release 0.7.0*